# Where to find MAVLink_ROS document?

Tags: ros, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm just trying to use the MAVLink_ROS [package](https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink_ros), but I cannot find any document/wiki/tutorial related.

Its [page](http://wiki.ros.org/mavlink-ros-pkg) on ROS wiki has been removed, also no wiki in the github or qgroundcontrol.org

Could anyone tell me where can I find some useful information?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166571/where-to-find-mavlink_ros-document?/) by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI you could try this python generator:

https://github.com/posilva/mav2rosgenerator

Best

Pedro

---

Originally posted by [pmosilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/19772/pmosilva/) with karma: 56 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0